Is a monotone and Lipschitz continuous operator weakly sequentially continuous?
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $F:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ be monotone, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathcal{H}) \quad \langle x-y, F(x) - F(y)\rangle\geq 0,
\end{equation}
and $L$-Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathcal{H}) \quad \|F(x) - F(y)\|\leq L \| x-y\|,
\end{equation}
for some $L>0$.
Suppose that $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $x^{*}$. Is it true that $(F(x_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $F(x^{*})$?

No. As a counterexample you can take $F$ to be the metric projection of the closed unit ball $B$ of $\ell^2$, which is (maximal) monotone and non-expansive (i.e. 1-Lipschitz). In this answer it is shown that $F$ is not weak-to-weak sequentially continuous.

In general maximal monotone operators are not weak-to-weak closed or weak-to-weak sequentially continuous. However, there is an interesting fact:

Fact. (Corollary 2.4 in [1]) If $F \colon H \to H$ is maximal monotone and $x_n \xrightarrow{w} x$, $ F(x_n) \xrightarrow{w} u $ satisfy
$$ \limsup_n \langle x_n,F(x_n) \rangle \le \langle x, u \rangle $$
then $u = F(x)$.

[1] Barbu, Viorel. Nonlinear differential equations of monotone types in Banach spaces. Springer Science & Business Media, 2010.

No. Let $\Omega$ be a standard probability space and $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\Omega)$. Let $F: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ be given by $F(f) = \max\{f, 0\}$. Then $F$ is easily seen to be monotone and $1$-Lipschitz continuous. If $\{x_k\}$ is a sequence of iid fair coin toss random variables defined on $\Omega$, with values in $\{\pm 1\}$, then as $\{x_k\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, it converges weakly to $0$. But $F(x_k)$ converges weakly to $\frac{1}{2} \neq 0 = F(0)$.
